# Using React with Bootstrap and I want to start a row pull four data sets, put them into col then start a new row with the next 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, graphql

Using React with reactstrap and I want to start a row pull four data sets, put them into col then start a new row with the next 4. I have no problem mapping over and putting all the data in its own col but I only want four per row. Thank you for your Help.

```js
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import Lake from './Lake';

const ALL_LAKES_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_LAKES_QUERY {
    allLakes {
      id
      name
      address
      address2
      city
      state
      zip
      description
      photo {
        image {
          publicUrlTransformed
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function Lakes() {
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(ALL_LAKES_QUERY);
  console.log(data, error, loading);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading....</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          {data.allLakes.map((lake) => (
            <Col xs="3">
              <Lake key={lake.id} lake={lake} />
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using the xs prop on the Row component. It would only be a single row, but every 4 columns would wrap to a new line.

If you really want to separate every 4 columns to a new  then you should transform the array into a nested array structure to allow for this.